# Use source model to checkboxes in catalog attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes, checkbox, source-model

I have the code that create new attribute for category

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'watermark', array(
'group'         => 'Category labels',
'input'         => 'checkboxes',
'type'          => 'int',
'label'         => 'Labels',
'source'        => 'productlabels/source_watermark_category',
'backend'       => '',
'frontend'      => '',
'class'         => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => true,
'searchable'    => true,
'filterable'    => true,
'comparable'    => true,
'used_in_product_listing' => true,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'visible_in_advanced_search'  => true,
'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
'unique'        => false,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
```

));

and source model

```
class Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model_Source_Watermark_Category extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
implements Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Interface
{
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->getCollection();

    foreach ($collection as $value) {
        $watermark = !empty($value->getCategoryImage()) ? $value->getCategoryImage() : '';
        $result[] = ['value' => $value->getId(), 'label' => $value->getTitle(), 'watermark' => $watermark];
    }

    return $html;
}
}
```

Why my source model doesn`t working, but if i choose *select* instead *checkboxes* it will be good.

Comment: did you try instead of `'input'         => 'checkboxes',` to use `'input'         => 'checkbox',`  ?

Comment: yes, it doest't work the same, but i need 'checkboxes'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just did some research and there is no support for multiple checkboxes as an attribute display in Magento 1.

You would have to make a full custom implementation to make this work.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: As far as I read, its a real pain. Why can't you just use `select`?

Comment: I need output list images and there possible check few images

Comment: You can just have a `yes` or `no` selection

Comment: Look at tab Product Labels http://rwd-product-labels.demo.amasty.com/rwd-product-labels/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/886/[link], i need do the same

Comment: Sorry, this is not what your question was. You asked why `'input'         => 'checkboxes',` was not working and I explained it to you

Comment: @ПетроЧайківський would be nice if you accepted my answer since It answered your question